# key DDNS_UPDATE unknown key

Tags: bind

After upgraded isc-dhcp-server and keep my config I've a strange error like logs below:

```
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: key DDNS_UPDATE;
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: ^

ping-check true;
one-lease-per-client true;
get-lease-hostnames true;
update-conflict-detection false;
ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style interim;
update-static-leases on;
allow unknown-clients;
use-host-decl-names on;
include "/etc/dhcp/rndc.key";

zone bunker.org. {
        primary localhost;
        key DDNS_UPDATE;
        }

zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
        primary localhost;
        key DDNS_UPDATE;
        }
```

and logs here:

```
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 30: unknown key DDNS_UPDATE
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: key DDNS_UPDATE;
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: ^
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 35: unknown key DDNS_UPDATE
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: key DDNS_UPDATE;
Sep 21 20:02:03 asia isc-dhcp-server[24548]: ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your zone so:

```
zone bunker.org. {
        primary 192.168.1.212;
        key rndc-key;
        }

zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
        primary 192.168.1.212;
        key rndc-key;
        }
```